# What databases support a mix of ACID and BASE at a column level?

Tags: database

I'm looking (mostly out of curiousity) for a database that supports a mix of ACID and BASE consistency for different columns in a row.

A simple example use of this is an inventory control system; for a given item, the stock level should be updated accross replicas immediately, whilst a typo correction in a description can propogate more slowly.

If this doesn't already exist, I'll gladly write my own solution, but am assuming I'm not the first person to think of this.